# How to extract part of multidimensional array tree with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a huge dynamically generated tree. The tree is generated from a flat array based on each elements "parent_id" attribute.

The final result would for example look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 70
            [name] => Top Corp
            [parent_id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 43
                            [name] => Department
                            [parent_id] => 70
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 45
                                            [name] => Building
                                            [parent_id] => 43
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 75
                                                            [name] => Office
                                                            [parent_id] => 45
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )
```

How do I extract just a part of the array tree? What functions or methods should I look at?

E.g. how do I say another sub-level (potentially 20-30 levels deep) is now the top.

For example, a pseudo function of `sliceTree(45)` should produce the following result, aka start the tree from `id 45`

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 45
        [name] => Building
        [parent_id] => 43
        [children] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 75
                        [name] => Office
                        [parent_id] => 45
                    )

            )

    )
```

There is no way to know how deep the tree can go so it a solution needs to be recursive.

I have tried looping the array, looking for the starting id, but I am unsure of how to continue the execution after the point has been found.

My proposed solution is as follows

```
function sliceTree($tree, $id){
    $ret = [];
    foreach ($tree as $out) {
        // if the top level matches
        if($out["id"] == $id){
            array_push($ret, $out);
        }
        else {
            if(isset($out["children"])){
                foreach ($out["children"] as $c) {
                    if($c["id"] == $id){
                        array_push($ret, $c);
                    }
                   // probably needs to call itself here
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Which works, but only for top-level elements. How can I make recursive and account for the many levels of children?

Comment: _"I have tried..."_ - Please show us your attempts. With 3k in rep, you probably already know that we're here to help you with your code, but we're not here to write it for you.

Comment: I would also build a function to check tree integrity, and use that first. Clearly `45FI34ULrRmYgOixhH` is not the correct `parent_id`.

Comment: Problem is I am unsure what to try. So far it's a normal foreach where if the id matches I can continue execution, but I am not sure what to do. @KIKOSoftware - sorry, a manual typing error

Comment: _"Problem is I am unsure what to try"_ - But you say that you _have_ tried something. And that's what we need to see. You should already know this.

Comment: You are right @MagnusEriksson. I have updated the first post with the best solution I have managed to whip up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sliceTree()` function basically looks for a certain `id` and returns it. Something like this:

```
function sliceTree($tree, $branchId)
{
    // check all branches
    foreach ($tree as $branch) {
        // have we found the correct branch?
        if ($branch['id'] == $branchId) return $branch;
        // check the children
        if (isset($branch['children'])) {
            $slice = sliceTree($branch['children'], $branchId);
            if (isset($slice)) return $slice;
        } 
    }
    // nothing was found
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, this routine is recursive. *Code is untested.*

I'm sorry about the mixed metaphors: branches and children, but you started it.

This function is slightly more complex, than I would like it to be, because in your example the `children` key is absent when there are no children. I would normally expect it to be there and the value to be an empty array.

Comment: Wonderful, that's it. Thanks - I have also taken your advice and made it less complex by adding an empty array even if there's no children so I do not have to explicitly check for that.